# Prove that in a binary tree there exists a leaf with depth at least $\log_2 n$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, induction, trees

It can be certainly tackled with induction method, but I'm not sure what metrics to use for induction. Hints will be appreciated. Also root level $= 0$.

Comment: probably logarithm base two. you also need to define for us the depth in your tree: is the root depth zero or depth one?

Comment: Probably there is no point to work with case, when root level = 1. For example, I can pick complete binary tree with 3 vertices, then for any leaf their depth will be equal to $\log_2 3 < 2$, and this is contradicts with statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Show by induction on $n$ that a [perfect binary tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree#Types_of_binary_trees) of depth $n$ has $2^{n+1}-1$ vertices. If a binary tree $T$ has no leaf of depth at least $n$, then the depth of $T$ is at most $n-1$, so $T$ has at most $2^n-1$ vertices. Now take logs base $2$.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get it. Basically by taking log base two from the number of vertices we just cut the last level of the tree, right? So here I'm supposed to take logs till I get the value that is smaller than the number of vertices in my tree or not?

Comment: @Purifyingflames: No, just replace $n$ by $\lg n$. If a binary tree has no leaf of depth at least $\lg n$, then the depth of $T$ is less than $\lg n$, so $T$ has fewer than $2^{\lg n}=n$ vertices.